# Draw multiple 'static progress bar' in android

Tags: android

How do I draw multiple 'static progress bar' in android? I want to achieve the exact same thing as in the image below

[image: static progress bar]

Setting up a canvas for each for the 'static progress bar' would be too troublesome, no? Is there any quicker and cleaner way to achieve the same thing like the image?

Comment: I am trying to do the same, could you please add the approach you took? Thanks!

Comment: @Codedroid I just use the ProgressBar control

Answer (score 1):

Here is a usefull tutorial on how to create your custom horizontal progressbar. [Take a look](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.ro/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-progress-bar-and.html).

Comment: this one is overkill for me. what I'm actually trying to achieve is not a progress bar per-se, instead something that does only look like a progress bar. and the bar is static

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="50 % (optional)"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```